# Russian language in html file

Tags: html, cyrillic

I have a simple page which shows `????????????`,It is russian language and i want to show it as it is

```
<!DOCTYPE>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
 <body>
тыуиппюлкйчг
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, though you should probably set the content type and character encoding in the response header instead of using the <meta> tag here.

Comment: I resolved it by going to dreamweaver->modify-?page properties and then select UTF there

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that:

- Your editor is configured to save the file using UTF-8 *and*
- Whatever method you are using to put the file on the server is not mangling the encoding (e.g. use FTP binary mode and not text mode) *and*
- Your server is not sending a `Content-Type` HTTP response header that contradicts (and overrides) the document level declaration that the document is UTF-8.

Comment: And ensure that the server isn't converting it to a different encoding on output, either. ;)

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan — Since it appears to be a static file, I'm assuming that isn't the case.